# Is there a way to suppress the output when compiling multiple vhd files except for errors?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim, questasim

I have a compilation script I run before simulating on QuestaSim 10.7:

```
vcom -vhdl -2008 my_lib -check_synthesis src/mux.vhd
vcom -vhdl -2008 my_lib -check_snythesis src/clockdivdeby2.vhd
...
```

I receive an output on terminal as follows:

```
vcom -vhdl -2008 my_lib -check_synthesis src/mux.vhd
-- Loading package STANDARD
-- Loading package TEXTIO
-- Loading package std_logic_1164
-- Loading package std_logic_arith
-- Loading package STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED
-- Compiling entity eop_counter_tb
-- Compiling architecture rtl of eop_counter_tb
-- Loading entity eop_counter
End time: HH:MM:SS on Mon, DY, YEAR, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
vcom -vhdl -2008 my_lib -check_synthesis src/mux2.vhd
-- Loading package STANDARD
-- Loading package TEXTIO
-- Loading package std_logic_1164
-- Loading package std_logic_arith
-- Loading package STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED
-- Compiling entity eop_counter_tb
-- Compiling architecture rtl of eop_counter_tb
-- Loading entity eop_counter
** Error: src/mux2.vhd (LINE NUMBER): something something, bad syntax
End time: HH:MM:SS on Mon, DY, YEAR, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 1, Warnings: 0
```

I was wondering, is it possible to suppress the output message of loading and compiling and timing? I would like to know the errors and warnings however. Something like this:

```
vcom -vhdl -2008 my_lib -check_synthesis src/mux.vhd
Errrors: 0, Warnings: 0
vcom -vhdl -2008 my_lib -check_synthesis src/badfile.vhd
** Error: src/badfile.vhd(LINE NUMBER): something something, bad synthax
Errrors: 1, Warnings: 0
```

I do know that the whole output can be logged. However, I wanted to know right away if there are any errors instead of opening the file and searching for it in the log file.

Comment: First check if there are options to `vcom` then see if it is segregating output between stdout and stderr in any useful way.  In desperation, on a unix-like system you could combine the two output streams and pipe through `grep` designed to accept or ignore a number of things, something like `vcom -whatever 2>&1 | grep 'Error\|Something Else You Want to See'`

Comment: Perfect man! Idk why I didn't think of grep. I did `source COMPILE_ME_SCRIPT | grep 'vcom\|Error'` to print out each vcom command, error & warning report and it automagically prints error message if it has one. Best answer for sure

Comment: Interesting that the output is on stdout and not stderror.  Anyway, glad it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if there are options to `vcom` which accomplish what you want.

Then see (at least on a unix-like system) if it is segregating output between `stdout` and `stderr` in any useful way.

In desperation, on a unix-like system a technique you can use to solve this type of problem *for just about any command-line tool* is to combine the two output streams and pipe through one (or more) instances of `grep` instructed to pass or ignore a customized set of things.

For example,

`vcom -whatever 2>&1 | grep 'Error\|Something Else You Want to See'`

Would pass only lines containing one of those two patterns.

- `2>&1` is `bash` syntax to merge `stderr` with `stdout`, other shells will do this differently.
- The escaped vertical bar is a logical "or"
- Beware that the patterns are [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) not simple strings.  Certain characters will have special meanings unless escaped.  If you're feeling lazy you can also replace ones you're uncertain about with the single-character wildcard `.`

You can also do a negative match to reject things

`vcom -whatever 2>&1 | grep -v 'Loading package'`

And you can string together multiple instance of `grep`, or even use `sed` to alter messages, for example to get errors into a format where some IDE's driver can recognize line numbers and make them clickable.   Worth noting however that if you pipe together instances (so the earlier stages output is no longer a terminal) on a longer-running job, you may want to use the `--line-buffered` option to `grep` so that it outputs on a continuous basis rather than block buffering.

Finally the program `tee` can be useful to give you both live output and capture to a file.